# Listing specific file name in java

Tags: java

I want to list and print them out my src folder. But program is listing all files like .bin .classpat .project. I want to list and print only .ncat extension files. How can i do that ?

```
File f = null;
String[] paths;
try{      
    f = new File("C:/Users/BURAK NURÇİÇEK/workspace/cs 222");
    paths = f.list();
    for(String path:paths){
        System.out.println(path);
    }
}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: A quick google search would probably turn up several examples (some maybe even on this site!) of how to do this. Do a little bit of research before coming to SO please.

Answer (score 5):

You can define a FileNameFilter :

```
String[] list = dir.list(new FilenameFilter() {
    @Override
    public boolean accept(File file, String name) {
        return name.endsWith("suffix");
    }
});
```

Comment: How can i adapt this code to my code ? Can you write ?

Comment: Well, consider it's part of your homework. This answer is 99% of what you've got to do. You need to think and understand for the last percent !

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow.

Take a look at the *String.endsWith(String suffix)* method (see
[here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#endsWith(java.lang.String)))
and make use of an if-condition.

**Update**

There is a better solution to this problem. Because this is a homework question (as the questioner mentioned) I will continue to elaborate the obvious way. One may google for FileFilter if he is required to use the "more professional" way.

Moving on: You are iterating over all files that are "stored" inside your *paths* variable (the for-loop). Inside the loop you are currently printing every file name. What you want to do, is to check if a file ends with the desired extension. If this condition is true, you can print it. If not: don't do anything.

Comment: There are much better ways of doing this using the `listFiles` method with a filter.

Comment: @rmlan: I assumed that this could be a "homework" or "learning" related question and therefore suggested the easy and obvious approach.

Comment: how can i read created file with getter instead of "C:/Users/BURAK NURÇİÇEK/workspace/cs 222" ?

Comment: @rmlan I wouldn't blame him. He just asked for help and mentioned that this is a homework question. The problem are (in my opinion) people who immediately post the full answer/code instead of guiding one to the solution. But homework question are an easy source for reputation points.

Comment: @BurakÇiçek Please consider updating your original question (using the edit function) so that everyone who visits this thread can see the changes.

Answer (score 0):

Easy way would be to check if the path ends with the extension as follows:

```
File f = null;
String[] paths;
try{      
    f = new File("C:/Users/BURAK NURÇİÇEK/workspace/cs 222");
    paths = f.list();
    for(String path:paths){
        if(path.toLowerCase().endsWith(".ncat")){
            System.out.println(path);
        }
    }
}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: @BurakÇiçek code should work now, I had made a mistake!

Comment: how can i read created file with getter instead of "C:/Users/BURAK NURÇİÇEK/workspace/cs 222" ?

Answer (score 0):

try this
public void filter(){

```
    String[] paths;
    try{      
        f = new File("C:/Users/BURAK NURÇİÇEK/workspace/cs 222");
        paths = f.list(new FilenameFilter() {
            @Override
            public boolean accept(File file, String name) {
                return name.endsWith("txt");
            }
        });

        for(String path:paths){
            System.out.println(path);
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```