# Checking existing file empty or not in java

Tags: java, file

My code is listing .ncat files and printing them to screen. I want to print if there is no .ncat files in directory, it prints out " there is no .ncat files" How can i do that ?

```
enter code here

            File f = null;
            String[] paths;

            try{      
                f = new File("C:/Users/BURAK NURÇİÇEK/workspace/cs 222");

                paths = f.list();

                for(String path:paths)
                {
                    if(path.toLowerCase().endsWith(".ncat")){
                        System.out.println(path);
                    }
                }
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: Please start taking your courses seriously, this is a second question from a second profile, trying to split an assignment in smaller problems that people will solve for you. - Original was: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35753884/listing-specific-file-name-in-java/35753971#35753971

Answer (score 1):

File has an exists() method. You can check

```
(new File(path)).exists()
```

Comment: no there is a file. but i want to this file empty or not ?

Comment: That will return true in the event that there are files that are not .ncat files in the directory.

Answer (score 1):

An extremely simple and clear way is to just set a flag to indicate if a `.ncat` file has been found. If no `.ncat` was in the directory, the flag will remain false and the statement will be printed. Try the following:

```
        File f = null;
        String[] paths;
        boolean fileFound = false;
        try{      
            f = new File("C:/Users/BURAK NURÇİÇEK/workspace/cs 222");

            paths = f.list();

            for(String path:paths)
            {
                if(path.toLowerCase().endsWith(".ncat")){
                    System.out.println(path);
                    fileFound = true;

                }
            }
            if (!fileFound) System.out.println("There are no .ncat files");
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the buffer reader class:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("pathToFile"));     
if (br.readLine() == null) {
    System.out.println("File is empty");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Checking existing file empty or not in java

To check whether a file is ***empty***:

```
if(new File(pathname).length() > 0)
```

To check whether a file ***exist***:

```
if(new File(pathname).exists())
```

To check whether a file exist in a folder and all it sub-directories, you can recursively check through the folder.

Answer (score 0):

```
int numberOfFiles = new File(path).listFiles().length;

if(numberOfFiles == 0) {
  System.out.println("Empty Directory");
}
```